# MATLAB: Plotting only ponts with colorbar based on another variable

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colormap

I want to plot only data points. Now I can plot the points which only considers 1 type of point. But my data contains different column variables. I want to plot different figures with different x and y variables from the data. Suppose I want to plot variable `D` against variable `A` or variable `E` against variable `year` but I want to plot data points with different colors or different types of points either *, dot, diamond etc. based on suppose, variable `pub` or variable `E`. Now for colormap I want to show colormap beside the figure with where the range of the variable value will be shown. For different type of points the point indexes will be suppose another variable `E`.

Also the 1st data should have a completely different point so that it can be distinguishable. My code actually shows different point for that data but it also plots with others.

Here is the truncated [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8a6yqcrar8ber5/Data.xlsx?dl=0).

Can anyone help me with that?

My code:

```
T = readtable('Data.xlsx');

year = T.Year;
pub = T.Publication;
A = T.A;
B = T.B;
C = T.C;
D = T.D;
E = T.F;

% Plot Data
f = figure;
%hold on; grid on, box on;
plot(A, D,'*')
hold on;
plot(A(1), D(1),'d')
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like [this matlab example](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#btrli6o-1_1) should be pretty close to what you want. It is a `scatter` plot (like your `plot(A,D,'*')` command), and has a colour scale that varies with a third variable `c`.

You should then combine this with a `hold on` command and plotting the first point using a different style suitable to your liking. You could something along the lines of the following (I have not downloaded your data, so I will use the example from the matlab link I provided):

```
x = linspace(0,3*pi,200);     % Independent variable
y = cos(x) + rand(1,200);     % Dependent variable
c = linspace(1,10,length(x)); % Colour variable

% Plot all points except the first one using colours in c and size 50:
scatter( x(2:end), y(2:end), 50, c(2:end) );
hold on

% Plot first point differently: twice the size, and with a filled marker:
scatter( x(1), y(1), 100, c(1), 'filled');
legend({'Data','First point'});
hold off
```